# What is the significance of the times after the closing credits in Diddy Kong Racing 64?

Tags: diddy-kong-racing

After defeating Wizpig in space in Adventure 2 (and possible after the normal adventure; I can't quite remember as it's been some time since I've played), when the credits roll, there are times given for each of the levels.  These times are extremely fast, and I remember only ever being able to beat one of them after a hundred tries or so.

What is the significance of these times?  They are shown with no context, just a level-name and a time.  Does anything special happen if you manage to beat them all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are the Developer's best recorded times...

> Defeat Wizpig for the second time.
>   After the ending and credits, a series
>   of times will be listed. These times
>   are the best times recorded (in Time
>   Trial mode) by Nintendo and Rare staff
>   during the production of the game.

There is nothing special (in-game) for beating these times.

Source: [Gamespot Tips link to quote is from.](http://www.gamespot.com/n64/driving/diddykongracing/hints.html)

Comment: Are the developer times faster than the ghost times needed to unlock TT?